# How to apply a mask to a number or string in Python?

Tags: python

I don't know if masks can only be applied to strings or numbers so I included both in my title (since I can always translate between the two later).

Let's say I have a mask `mask = '001001'` and I want to somehow say "for all positions in the mask that equal 1, apply X to those same positions in this other string".

For instance say I have a number 123456 and I apply that mask to it and want to set the digits to 0. I'd get 120450.

Apologies if I am not making sense. Please suggest an ideal mask type if my earlier string example is not the best, and an easy way to use it to apply changes to a separate number/string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [272]: mask = '001001'

In [273]: num=123456

In [274]: "".join(x if y!='1' else '0' for x,y in zip(str(num),mask))
Out[274]: '120450'
```

use `itertools.izip_longest()` if the number and the mask string are of different length:

```
In [277]: mask = '001001'

In [278]: num=12345678

In [279]: "".join(x if y!='1' else '0' for x,y in izip_longest(str(num),mask,fillvalue="#"))
Out[279]: '12045078'
```

Comment: I understand this solution except for how zip(str(num),mask) works -- would you mind explaining what exactly that does here?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian read about `zip()` in [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).